# Different ways of appending to the DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

Traditionally Ive been appending HTML content to the page like so:

```
var text='Some text';
var num=0;
$('#div').append('<div id="a'+num+'">'+text+'</div>');
```

But recently Ive been noticing a lot of this approach in other peoples code:

```
var text='Some text';
var num=0;
var newElement=$('<div></div>').text(text).prop('id','a'+num);
$('#div').append(newElement);
```

Can someone explain to me the advantages of the second approach, and whether I should move over to this approach or whether I should keep appending like I always have been.

Comment: I think it's mostly personal preference--keeping variables and DOM actions separate can make for code that's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is way faster than the second, mainly because it is just concating some string and directly appending the html

While in the second, you're doing `.text()` and `.prop()` which is a bit over kill than string concatenation..

The [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/concating-vs-appending) also proves that the first method is the way to go. Though the second one is more readable, the first is faster. You choose what you want.

<sub>In my laptop, the second method was 19% slower than the first.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Use your first approach if you do not need to alter the DOM element you are adding.

The second approach is more expensive, since you are creating a jQuery selector. This is only useful if you want to animate, fade, or do something further with the element you are creating, and need reference to it.